# In the windows if I want windows name (like:"Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise") not like: ({Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0) using Environment?

Tags: windows-8

I tried to get the windows name by using System.Environment.OSVersion but it gives name like Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0 but i want the name like Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise.Please suggest how can use the "Environment" by which i get the answer

Answer (score 1):

Based on the linked SO question, you can use `Get-WmiObject` in PowerShell to use the [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.

Ex:

```
PS C:\Users\Louis> (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro with Media Center
```

You can also use WMI from C#:

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WMISample
{
    public class MyWMIQuery
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"); 

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_OperatingSystem instance");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Caption: {0}", queryObj["Caption"]);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can u please tell step by step to add this

Comment: @user266752 I've added a C# demo.

Answer (score 1):

As a c# person I grit my teeth, reference Microsoft.VisualBasic dll and...

```
string os = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().OSFullName.ToString();
```

A couple of examples from our logging app (with what System.Environment.OSVersion returns)

Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro 
(vs. Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0)

Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
(vs. Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7600.0)

Microsoft Windows 7 Professional 
(vs. Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1)

Microsoft Windows XP Professional
(vs. Microsoft Windows NT 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3)

Answer (score 0):

there is no buildin way. You must use the [GetProductInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see which SKU you use and manually write the string.